# Linux kernel char driver write call is not working as expected

Tags: c, linux, kernel, mutex

I am trying to implement a FIFO using character driver. However while writing to the device it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't seems to end the loop. Any help or link is appreciated. I have taken help from many sources so current code is kind of mess with many things which shouldn't be as they are.

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off) {
int mode;
int ind;
ssize_t count = -ENOMEM;
printk(KERN_ALERT "to be written : %s\n", buff);
mode = iminor(filp->f_dentry->d_inode);
printk(KERN_ALERT "Device minor : %d\n", mode);
if ((mode == 1) || (mode ==3))
        return -EINVAL;
if (mode == 0){
    count = 0;
    ind = 0;
    if (buff[ind] == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position1 : %d\n", writePos1);
    while(ind<=len) {  //loop untill we have something to writer
        if (down_interruptible(&buffer1_e)) { //taking flag first isn't right because that won't allow other guyto give access to our turn.
                printk(KERN_ALERT "buffer1 flag didn't work\t %d", buffer1_e.count);
                return -ERESTARTSYS;
        }
        else {
            if (down_interruptible(&flag1)){
                up(&buffer1_e);         //must because we couldn't write it properly
                return -EINVAL;
            }
            else {
                queue1[writePos1] = buff[ind];
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Write %d %c\n",ind,queue1[writePos1]);
                if (writePos1 == 9){
                     writePos1 = 0;
                }
                else
                     writePos1++;
                count++;
            }
            up(&flag1);
        }
        up(&buffer1_f);
        off += count;
        ind++;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position1 now: %d\t and count%d\n", writePos1,count);
    return count-1;
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to compile a kernel module yet that can return strings written to it when doing echo "string" > /dev/device > ; cat /dev/device ? I could provide this. Also, I tried to compile your code - I couldn't since this is just a snippet.

Comment: This code is missing most of the required items of a Linux device driver.  And here is one of the problems in the code that is provided (there are others) 'while(ind<=len) {' This line should be: 'while(ind<len) {'  To be equal would result in accessing beyond the end of the input buffer (in C, indexing starts at 0 and the last entry is when index is len-1

Comment: You might want to read this : <http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x579.html> which discusses, with code, how to write a char device driver.

Comment: Here is the full code which I am trying to execute [link](http://pastebin.com/gP5dmvSQ) and this is my related kernel log [link](http://pastebin.com/zQsVmJcH). Write call is not returning correct value. But I am returning count variable which in print is correct.

Comment: @sum-it I have run your code. It seems to work fine. I modified it very slightly to print out the "to be written" string differently - passing it just the buffer pointer without a length causes it to overrun for me. The other differences might be how you are writing to the driver perhaps. You can find your code and my output here: github.com/n-hutton/kernelCharacterBuffer . Should be able to check it easily with make;make run. There is also a file output.txt which shows the output. Note that passing in a string of over 100 will cause the Message string to overwrite itself (in my version).

Comment: Thank you Nathan. That was much detailed. However my problem is still not solved. If I am correct this driver works on minor numbers. If it is 0 it will read from device and if it is 1 it will write to it. I have created two devices /dev/fifo0 and /dev/fifo1 for the same. If you can see in my previous log file. I can successfully write characters. But that write call doesn't seems to end and is looping itself. I am using: echo "test_msg" | cat >/dev/fifo0 to write into device. and simple cat /dev/fifo1 to read from it. Hope it could clear my problem.

Comment: @sum-it - Hello, I have identified at least one bug - for a correctly operating read operation, you are returning 0. You should return the number of bytes the driver has written to the buffer.


You can find the new code, as before at github.com/n-hutton/kernelCharacterBuffer . Also, you said that the driver numbers were 0 and 1 for read and write but I think it is the other way around. 


You can see in my new Makefile that I create two devices and can echo to one and cat from the other.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. :)
It works for the first few byte but not thereafter. I will have another look in the source and will let you know once I could find out the issue.

Comment: @sum-it - Yes, I see that it will only read and write once for me also. Looking at the code, I suspect this may due to readPos1 and writePos1 being incorrect.

If I were you I would consider writing this module from the ground up, rather than copying a lot of code. This will help in finding bugs, as you write and test it step by step. Also, I note your character buffer queue1 is only 10 long. I expect that writing more than 10 characters to this at once won't be pleasant. You could do it as a heap-allocated linked list?

Comment: I just modified it a bit. Now I think first queue is working as expected. [code](http://pastebin.com/kh5id3h6). Now if you supply it more than 10 characters as well using echo and cat it will accept. but block till characters are not read from writer. if you will read from other devices in the meanwhile it will complete execution as soon as all devices are written on the buffer. Can you have a look and suggest. Problem with earlier code was overflowing of writePos1 which overflows to next position after filling queue. making readPos1==writePos1 satisfy which is also buffer empty position.

Comment: this implied writer couldn't write because buffer is full. and reader will not read because it thinks queue is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I corrected complete code. It is very much immature, illogical for few logics still it works the I would like to do it. @Nathan Hutton helped a lot in improving it and making it work. I thank him for that. Though there are many things I still have one major doubt, if you could trace it in kernel logs, an extra line feed character is added every time whenever you write to a device with (echo "test" |cat >/dev/fifo0) 
to run it properly you will also need to create 4 char devices with Major number 240, minor 0,1,2,3. mknod can be used as:
"mknod /dev/fifo(0,1,2,3) c 240 (0,1,2,3) -m 777" //0,1,2,3 at a time and 777 can be modified for granularity. Finally working code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>

#define DEVNO 240
#define DEVNAME "fifo"
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(writing1);
//static short writeFlag1=0;
static DEFINE_SEMAPHORE(flag1);
static DEFINE_SEMAPHORE(flag2);
static struct semaphore buffer1_f;
static struct semaphore buffer2_f;
static struct semaphore buffer1_e;
static struct semaphore buffer2_e;

DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(writing2);
//static short writeFlag2=0;

static char queue1[10]={0};
static short readPos1=0;
static short writePos1=0;
//static short qsize1=0;

static char queue2[10]={0};
static short readPos2=0;
static short writePos2=0;
//static short qsize2=0;

static int times=0;

static int dev_open(struct inode *,struct file *);
static int dev_rls(struct inode *,struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *,char *,size_t,loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *,const char *,size_t,loff_t *);

static struct file_operations fops={
  .read=dev_read,
  .write=dev_write,
  .open=dev_open,
  .release=dev_rls,
};

int init_module(void){
  unsigned int devno = 240;
  char *devname = "fifo";
  int t;
  sema_init(&buffer1_f,0);
  sema_init(&buffer2_f,0);
  sema_init(&buffer1_e,10);
  sema_init(&buffer2_e,10);
  memset(queue1,0,10);
  memset(queue2,0,10);
  t=register_chrdev(devno,devname,&fops);
  if(t<0) printk(KERN_ALERT "device reg failed. \n");
  else printk(KERN_ALERT "Device registered. \n");
  return t;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
  unregister_chrdev(240,"fifo");
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Device has been removed");
}

static int dev_open(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil){
  times++;
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Device opened %d times\n",times);
  return 0;
}

static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off) {
  int mode = iminor((filep->f_dentry->d_inode));
  short count;
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Device minor when read : %d\n", mode);
  if ((mode == 0) || (mode ==2))
      return -EINVAL;
  else if (mode == 1){
    count = 0;
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Read position1 when read: %d\n", readPos1);
    while(len) {  //loop untill we have something to write or empty buffer
      if (readPos1==writePos1){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Returning chars put to buffer: %d\n", count);
        return count;
      }
      if (down_interruptible(&buffer1_f)) {
          printk(KERN_ALERT "flag1 didn't work");
          return -ERESTARTSYS;
      }
      else {
        if (down_interruptible(&flag1)){
          return -EINVAL;
        }
        else {
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Read %c\n",queue1[readPos1]);
          put_user(queue1[readPos1],buff++);
                    if (writePos1==-1) writePos1=readPos1;
          if (readPos1 == 9) readPos1 = 0;
          else readPos1++;
          count++;
        }
        up(&flag1);
      }
      up(&buffer1_e);
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Read position1 now: %d\t and count%d\n", readPos1,count);
    return count;  
  }
  else if (mode == 3){
    count = 0;
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Read position2 when read: %d\n", readPos2);
    while(len) {  //loop untill we have something to write or empty buffer
      if (readPos2==writePos2){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Returning chars put to buffer: %d\n", count);
        return count;
      }
      if (down_interruptible(&buffer2_f)) {
          printk(KERN_ALERT "flag2 didn't work");
          return -ERESTARTSYS;
      }
      else {
        if (down_interruptible(&flag2)){
          return -EINVAL;
        }
        else {
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Read %c\n",queue2[readPos2]);
          put_user(queue2[readPos2],buff++);
                    if (writePos2==-1) writePos2=readPos2;
          if (readPos2 == 9) readPos2 = 0;
          else readPos2++;
          count++;
        }
        up(&flag2);
      }
      up(&buffer2_e);
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Read position2 now: %d\t and count%d\n", readPos2,count);
    return count;  
  }
  else {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Not correct mode\n");
    return -1;
  }
}
static char Message[100] = "Initial message\n";
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off) {
  int mode;
  int ind;
  ssize_t count = -ENOMEM;
  int i;
  //Let's copy the message onto our stack so we can be clear what we are getting
  for (i = 0; i < 99 && i < len; i++){
    char getChar;
    get_user(getChar, buff + i);
    Message[i] = getChar;
  }
  Message[i] = '\0';
    printk(KERN_ALERT "to be written : %s\n", Message);
  mode = iminor(filp->f_dentry->d_inode);
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Device minor : %d\n", mode);
  if ((mode == 1) || (mode ==3))
    return -EINVAL;
  else if (mode == 0){
    count = 0;
    ind = 0;
    if (( buff == NULL) ||  (*buff == 0)) {
      return -ENOMEM;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position1 : %d\n", writePos1);
    while(ind<len) {  //loop untill we have something to writer
      if (down_interruptible(&buffer1_e)) { //taking flag first isn't right because that won't allow other guyto give access to our turn.
        printk(KERN_ALERT "buffer1 flag didn't work\t %d", buffer1_e.count);
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
      }
      else {
        if (down_interruptible(&flag1)){
          up(&buffer1_e);     //must because we couldn't write it properly
          return -EINVAL;
        }
        else {
          queue1[writePos1] = buff[ind];
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Write ind:%d writepos:%d readpos;%d char:%c\tascii%d\n",ind,writePos1,readPos1,queue1[writePos1],(int)queue1[writePos1]);
                    if (readPos1==((writePos1+1)%10)) {
                        writePos1=-1;
                    }
          else if (writePos1 == 9){
             writePos1 = 0;
          }
          else
             writePos1++;
          count++;
        }
                printk(KERN_ALERT "writepos:%d",writePos1);
        up(&flag1);
      }
      up(&buffer1_f);
      off += count;
      ind++;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position1 now: %d\t and count%d\n", writePos1,(int)count);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Note: our allowable buffer length was %d\n", (int)len);
    return count;
  }
  else if (mode == 2){
    count = 0;
    ind = 0;
    if (( buff == NULL) ||  (*buff == 0)) {
      return -ENOMEM;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position2 : %d\n", writePos2);
    while(ind<len) {  //loop untill we have something to writer
      if (down_interruptible(&buffer2_e)) { //taking flag first isn't right because that won't allow other guyto give access to our turn.
        printk(KERN_ALERT "buffer2 flag didn't work\t %d", buffer2_e.count);
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
      }
      else {
        if (down_interruptible(&flag2)){
          up(&buffer2_e);     //must because we couldn't write it properly
          return -EINVAL;
        }
        else {
          queue2[writePos2] = buff[ind];
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Write ind:%d writepos2:%d readpos2;%d char:%c\tascii%d\n",ind,writePos2,readPos2,queue2[writePos2],(int)queue2[writePos2]);
                    if (readPos2==((writePos2+1)%10)) {
                        writePos2=-1;
                    }
          else if (writePos2 == 9){
             writePos2 = 0;
          }
          else
             writePos2++;
          count++;
        }
                printk(KERN_ALERT "writepos:%d",writePos2);
        up(&flag2);
      }
      up(&buffer2_f);
      off += count;
      ind++;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Write position2 now: %d\t and count%d\n", writePos2,(int)count);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Note: our allowable buffer length was %d\n", (int)len);
    return count;
  }
  else {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "This meant wrong device minor accessed\n");
    return -1;
  }
}
static int dev_rls(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Device is closed\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote my own module and I *suspect* that your issue is that the process calling dev_write expects dev_write to return the number of bytes written. If you don't return the correct number (I see you are returning count - 1), dev_write will be called again and again.

dev_read I have found to be similar - until it returns 0, the process will repeatedly call it - expecting that there are more characters to be retrieved (this makes sense).

I have written/modified a much more simple module that illustrates using a module as a character buffer (sorry, it's quite hastily written). It should allow you to echo a string to it, and return that string when you cat or otherwise read from it. This is demonstrated when you `make run`. I am sure you will be able to easily modify it to become FIFO.

I don't accept any liability for crashing your kernel or other problems, and you should be using a VM anyway.

It is long, so on my github:

```
git clone https://github.com/n-hutton/tempRepo
cd tempRepo
make
make run
```